# An MVC guy trying to understand asp.net Web Forms (Databinding)

Tags: c#, webforms

I've been thrown on this project that uses Asp.net Webforms.

I'm trying to understand how data binding works.

Suppose I enter Form data regarding User Registration.  When I submit, can I bind the inputs to a Model somehow?

I've read about binding to Data Sets which could be XML.  Would I need to de-serialize this to some sort of entity?

Please, any resource on this would be appreciated.

Comment: How about the Microsoft Press book by Northrup and Snell for MCTS 70-515? They're funny and very didactic. "Web Applications Development with Microsoft .Net Framework".

Comment: Yes, you can create a model and store in ViewState and databind it on the frontend (code in-front, i say).  Give me a sec I will find my old code for this, its been years.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid datasets if you can. Use strongly typed objects instead. If you do use datasets, they already serialize nicely. Here is a crude example to get you on your way. This will pull values from the text boxes and bind a list view to the collection. 
I hope this helps.

Step 1: Create the Objects & View Model

```
 [Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    public Person(String FirstName, String LastName)
    {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
    }

    public Person()
        : this(String.Empty, String.Empty)
    {
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class ViewModelBase
{

}

[Serializable]
public class SomePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Person currentperson;
    public Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get
        {
            if (currentperson == null)
            {
                currentperson = new Person();
            }
            return currentperson;
        }
        set
        {
            currentperson = value;
        }

    }

    private List<Person> persons;
    public List<Person> Persons
    {
        get
        {
            if (persons == null)
            {
                persons = new List<Person>();
            }
            return persons;
        }
        set
        {
            persons = value;
        }
    }
    public SomePageViewModel()
    {
    }

    public void RegisterPerson(String FirstName, String LastName)
    {
        Persons.Add(new Person(FirstName,LastName));
    }
    public void GetPersons()
    {
        /*Get Persons from database*/
    }
}
```

Step 2: Instantiate the ViewModel in your code behind file (PageName.aspx.cs)

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Lazy initialized and persisted in session
    /// </summary>
    public SomePageViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            if (Session["SomePageViewModel"] == null)
            {
                Session.Add("SomePageViewModel", new SomePageViewModel());
            }
            return Session["SomePageViewModel"] as SomePageViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                if (Session["SomePageViewModel"] != null)
                {
                    Session.Remove("SomePageViewModel");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Session["SomePageViewModel"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Step 3: Add markup to the ASPX

```
   <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" ValidationGroup="vgrpRegister"  />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLastName" ValidationGroup="vgrpRegister" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnRegister" Text="Register"  ValidationGroup="vgrpRegister"/>

<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvPersons" ItemPlaceholderID="phPersons" DataSource='<%#ViewModel.Persons%>'>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="tblPersons" border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phPersons"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Eval("FirstName") %></td>            
            <td><%#Eval("LastName") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Step 4: CodeBehind Events

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnRegister.Click += new EventHandler(btnRegister_Click);
    }

    void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ViewModel.RegisterPerson(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text);
        this.lvPersons.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you need to use session here, viewstate would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Rod, You are correct that session is not needed and viewstate can hold the data but you have to remember that the viewstate will be serialized/deserialized on every post. You also cannot share data between multiple pages using viewstate. That said, session storage does have its own negatives. This is really up to the developer at the time.

Comment: Yes, you would essentially have to reload all the data you need on every request... sucks I know, this is a horrible framework.